# Map two classes to the same table

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

There is a NODES table with dozen of 'small' columns and a LOB column in a legacy DB. A NodeEntity class is mapped to the NODES table.

For performance purposes I do not want to load LOB column every time I access the DB. I know two approaches to achieve this:

- Lazy loaded properties
- Separate entity class (the idea is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42698599/skip-property-on-update-in-nhibernate))

Lazy loaded properties are good when you only loading data from DB. But if you have to save entities then there is a risk to lose your data if you forget to fetch lazy loaded properties beforehand.

So I chose the second approach.

I created separate small NodeEntityLite class with properties mapped to non-LOB columns of NODES table. I modified NodeEntity class so it inherits from NodeEntityLite class. I changed the mappings for my classes and used union-subclass for inheritance.

```
public class NodeEntityLite {
  public virtual long Id { get; set; }
  public virtual string Code { get; set; }
}
public class NodeEntity : NodeEntityLite {
  public virtual string NOTE { get; set; } // type:clob
}
```

FluentNHibernate mapping for NodeEntityLite class is

```
public void Override(AutoMapping<NodeEntityLite> mapping) {
    mapping.Table("NODES");
    mapping.UseUnionSubclassForInheritanceMapping();
}
```

FluentNHibernate mapping for NodeEntity class is

```
public void Override(AutoMapping<NodeEntity> mapping) {
    mapping.Table("NODES");
    mapping.Map(e => e.NOTE).CustomType("StringClob").CustomSqlType("NCLOB");
}
```

I expected that when I execute `select n from NodeEntityLite n where n.Id = :p0` HQL then NHibernate generates SQL commands without NOTE column:

```
select nodeentity0_.ID as id1_87_, 
       nodeentity0_.CODE as code2_87_
    from from NODES nodeentity0_ 
    where nodeentity0_.ID=:p0;
```

But NHibernate generates absolutely different SQL command (NOTE column is not skipped as I expected):

```
select nodeentity0_.ID as id1_87_, 
       nodeentity0_.CODE as code2_87_, 
       nodeentity0_.NOTE as note14_87_, 
       nodeentity0_.clazz_ as clazz_ 
    from ( select ID, CODE, NOTE, 1 as clazz_ from NODES ) nodeentity0_ 
    where nodeentity0_.ID=:p0;
```

I tried to change inheritance and to use other mappings but without success.

The question is: **Can I map several classes to the same table in NHibernate to get access to different columns?**

If yes, please give an example.

---

The solution (based on the suggestions from David Osborne and mxmissile) is **not to use inheritance**. I use common interface implementation instead of class inheritance. The working code is below:

```
public interface INodeLite {
  long Id { get; set; }
  string Code { get; set; }
}

public class NodeEntityLite : INodeLite {
  public virtual long Id { get; set; }
  public virtual string Code { get; set; }
}

public class NodeEntity : INodeLite {
  public virtual long Id { get; set; }
  public virtual string Code { get; set; }
  public virtual string NOTE { get; set; } // type:clob
}
...
public void Override(AutoMapping<NodeEntityLite> mapping) {
    mapping.Table("NODES");
}
...
public void Override(AutoMapping<NodeEntity> mapping) {
    mapping.Table("NODES");
    mapping.Map(e => e.NOTE).CustomType("StringClob").CustomSqlType("NCLOB");
}
```

Comment: What happens if you dont use inheritance and create completely separate entities?

Comment: Inheritance is imprortant since the code which process instances of NodeEntityLite must accept instances of NodeEntity also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of the inheritance, NH can map different types to the same table. I have done it, albeit without inheritance.

You should be able to remove this line from the `NodeEntityLite` override and achieve it:

```
mapping.UseUnionSubclassForInheritanceMapping();
```

If this proves unsuccessful, you might need to tune the automapping further. It's definitely possible though.

Comment: It looks like Fluent NHibernate detects that one entity class inherits from other class.

Comment: Ah. Can you tell it not to in the override for this hierarchy? Or maybe use composition over inheritance?

Comment: Fluent NHibernate detects that one entity class inherits from other class and if I remove `UseUnionSubclassForInheritanceMapping` then Fluent NHibernate generates joined-subclass inheritance mapping.
Your and @mxmissile suggestion not to use inheritance is good idea. I change the classes `NodeEntity` and `NodeEntityLite` so that they implement a common interface without inheritance.